# pandas.DataFrame.to_dict behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to transform my dataframe to a dict  , in order to use those dicts to instanciate some class objects. Following documentation, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html, the rule I need in my case is orient='records'.
However, I noticed that it does not behave as I expected when column names are integers,or strings containing only integer:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 15:[4,5,6], '302':[5,6,7]})
mydict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print(mydict)
```

returns

```
[{'_2':4, 'a':1, '_0':5},{'_2':5, 'a':2, '_0':6}, {'_2':6, 'a':3, '_0':7}]
```

I found a way to work around the problem, doing:

```
mydict = list(df.to_dict(orient='index').values())
```

but I am at loss as to why this is happening. I am on python `3.5` and on pandas `0.24`.
Any ideas?

Comment: I see your first `mydict` returning `[{'a': 1, 15: 2, '302': 3}, {'a': 2, 15: 3, '302': 4}, {'a': 3, 15: 4, '302': 5}]`. What *precisely* do you want as your desired output? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54531367/edit) to clarify?

Comment: @jpp I edited my question. I am at a loss as to why we do not get the same output. Note that I am on python 3.5 / pandas 0.24

Comment: Sorry, I reread your question, I have Pandas 0.19.2, so this *could* be a bug from a later version.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug that was introduced in pandas 0.24.0, and fixed in 0.24.1. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24940